# Como remover um valor de um conjunto que está dentro de um dicionário de conjuntos?

Tags: python

Por exemplo, se eu tiver um dicionário assim:

```
{
  x: { 1, 2, 3 },
  y: { 2, 3, 4 },
  z: { 1, 5, 6 }
}
```

Como faço pra remover todas as ocorrências de `2`?

Answer (score 1):

Basta iterar pelos conjuntos, e remover o `2` de cada um.

```py
dicionario = dict()

# Iniciando valores no dicionário
dicionario['x'] = set([1, 2, 3])
dicionario['y'] = set([2, 3, 4])
dicionario['z'] = set([1, 5, 6])

# Para cada conjunto...
for conjunto in dicionario.values():
    # Remova o valor 2
    conjunto.discard(2)

# Mostrar resultado
print(dicionario)
```

Eu utilizei o método `discard` em detrimento de `remove`, pois `remove` lança erro quando o item não pertence ao conjunto. Já o `discard` não faz nada, silenciosamente, que é o comportamento que desejamos.